# How to increase code coverage for apex class that contains only web callouts

Tags: code-coverage

I have an apex class which contains code only for web callouts and for this class I get coverage equivalent to 9% since actual web callouts are not a part of tests. So how am I supposed to increase code coverage for this class? I am not sure whether this % will allow the code to be deployed on PROD from Sandbox.

Basically I need to move 2 classes and 1 trigger to PROD with coverage as:

- Trigger - 89%
- Class 1 - 67%
- Class 2 (with Web callouts) - 9%

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any reason why writing unit tests with coverage does not work?

Comment: Unit tests are working and giving the mentioned coverage but since one of my class contains code only for web callout, so this code does not have much coverage. Do I need to create mock callouts and how will they help in increasing coverage of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apex mocks to achieve the goal. Apex mock is used to get a response from the callout you need. So when you are doing a callout

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('http://example.com/example/test');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http h = new Http();
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

the last line will basically return the result you want. To increase code coverage for method with if/else conditions you just need to create few mocks as inner classes which will return the result needed to get into this condition blocks. Salesforce have great [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm) for that.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.